# need help with regex

Tags: regex, match

In a string

```
mssql://text1:text2@text3/text4?ApplicationName=adfDGFSHG
```

I need to match

```
text1:text2@text3
```

and

```
text4
```

I wrote:

```
string ConnectionURL = "mssql://faerg:aassd@4235453tgr/he657i7u8kui?ApplicationName=adfDGFSHG";
Match m = Regex.Match(ConnectionURL, "mssql\\s*:\\s*//\\s*([\\d\\w\\s]*)/([\\d\\w\\s]*)\\?");
```

But that didn't match anything. Help is greatly appreciated :) .

Comment: How did the `http` part get into this regex?

Comment: Your string starts with mssql but you regex starts with http...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^mssql://([^/]+)/([^?]+)\?
```

Tested and tru on Rubular (needs escaping on `/`). Unfortunately, I am not able to create a permalink :(

Comment: this regex will also include `/` just before text4

Comment: @Abhishek Simon No, that `/` is not captured; it is between the two group (the first cannot be a `/` thus matching until that character; the second gruop will match until the `?`).

Answer (score 2):

Try with following regex:

```
^.*?//([a-z0-9@:]+)/([a-z0-9]+).*$
```

Comment: This regex select the whole url

Comment: `@Abhishek Simon` do you know how brackets `()` works in regex ?

Comment: +1 for this. People should at least make some effort to ensure they are correct before downvoting.

Comment: Thanks, @hsz, your solution works, but jensgram proposed the solution first, so I'll accept his answer .